# How to move the Marker's center origin point in Movie Clip Editor?

Tags: tracking, origin, movie-clip-editor, marker

I have a video with blurry lines in them, so I had to manually fine-adjust a lot of the markers per frame. I've already positioned the corners of a set of markers that use the *Affine* Motion Model and didn't realize that the center point went off target while I was too much focused on positioning the corners. It would be too tedious if I had to redo all of this. Since I can manually adjust the corners of the marker, I was wondering if it was also possible to manually adjust this marker's origin point encircled in yellow:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible with the current Blender versions